# Click hyperlink in selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that filters a sheet based on a certain value, then select a cell that contains a hyperlink and click on that hyperlink that leads to another sheet. I've already managed to achieve the first part but the hyperlink part isn't working, does anyone know how it could be done? Under these lines I'll copy the code I currently have and highlight the part that I have issues with. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub FilterBasedOnCellValueAnotherSheet()
Dim category As Range
Dim LR As Long
With Worksheets("Result")
Set category = .Range("B3")
End With
With Worksheets("Summary")
With .Range("B3:M300")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=category, VisibleDropDown:=True
End With
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("L3:L" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
**Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True**
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  Do you get an error?  If Yes what is it?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, when I run it it says: Error 9: Subscript out of interval and highlights the Selection.Hyperlinks part

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub FilterBasedOnCellValueAnotherSheet()
    Dim category As Range
    Dim LR As Long, rngVis As Range, c As Range
    
    Set category = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Range("B3")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B3:M300")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=category, VisibleDropDown:=True
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no visible rows
        Set rngVis = .EntireRow.Columns("L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    End With
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'follow the first link found
    For Each c In rngVis.Cells
        If c.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        Exit For
    Next c
End Sub
```